# Sorting data in one .txt file from highest to lowest and printing it to another text file

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have created a quiz for a  teacher and all the scores are stored in a file for each class for example, if a student was in class 1 their score would be copied into a text file called class1 and the data would be written like:

```
aaron, 1 
lllll, 10 
kkkkk, 7
```

However my next task is to create another program for the teacher to use so she types in which class she wants and what she wants it sorted in (alphabetically, average and highest to lowest) and it prints it when run. This is my code so far I have managed to do the alphabetical part but am struggling on the average and the highest to lowest part:

```
viewclass= input("choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?")


if viewclass=='1 alphabetically':
    with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')


elif viewclass=='2 alphabetically':
    with open('class2.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')

elif viewclass=='3 alphabetically':
    with open('class3.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')
```

Comment: unrelated: don't repeat the same code three times: use a function or take the filename from a `dict`.

Comment: Could you show the example input and output that corresponds to "average", and "highest to lowest" order?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I dont know what you mean???

Comment: Please don't use SO to cheat on your GCSEs.

Comment: @AaronLad: Are you referring to my first comment or the second one (or both)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian    the second one i'm just a beginner at coding

Comment: `a b c` is sorted "alphabetically". `c b a` is (probably) sorted "highest to lowest". I don't understand what order "average" specifies. Could you provide an example that illustrates "average" order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to define a proper sort `key` and to use `reverse`.  I presume for 'highest' you want the following.

```
r = '''\
aaron, 1
lllll, 10
kkkkk, 7'''.split('\n')
# r is an iterable of non-blank lines, like a file

def score(line):
    return int(line.split(',')[1])

for line in sorted(r, key=score, reverse=True):
    print(line)

###
lllll, 10
kkkkk, 7
aaron, 1
```

I do not know what you mean by 'average'.

Comment: by average i mean the scores added together and divided by how many there are. But i first need to do it so only the last 3 scores are stored for each student which is confusing me slightly